# I get a expected type parameter, even though I think I have returned the correct type data

Tags: types, rust, traits

I get a expected type parameter, even though I think I have returned the correct type data.I am in the learning phase of generic material in rust.

```
struct Cat {
    weight: i32,
}

trait Animal{
    fn get_weight<T>(&self) -> T;
}

impl Animal for Cat {
    fn get_weight<i32>(&self) -> i32 {
        self.weight // I got error in here
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Error message:

```
mismatched types

expected type parameter, found i32

note: expected type `i32` (type parameter)
         found type `i32` (i32)

expected `i32` because of return type
expected type parameter, found i32
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the compiler warning here is very helpful.

```
warning: type parameter `i32` should have an upper camel case name
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 |     fn get_weight<i32>(&self) -> i32 {
   |                   ^^^ help: convert the identifier to upper camel case: `I32`
   |
   = note: #[warn(non_camel_case_types)] on by default
```

As you can see, the `i32` between the brackets is being parsed as a type parameter. I believe this locally shadows the type `i32` (specifically, the return type is this generic type), so when you return a normal `i32`, the compiler complains. This isn't really relevant, since that isn't the root of the problem.

The problem here is that the `Animal` trait requires that its `get_weight` method be generic in `T`. When you implement the trait, you have to provide a `get_weight` method that works for *every* possible type `T` (with the implicit restriction that the type is `Sized`). This should be impossible, since you'd have to produce an element of any given type out of thin air. Some types don't even have any elements!

Instead, you have two choices. First, you could make a generic trait. The syntax for this is

```
trait Animal<T> {
    fn get_weight(&self) -> T;
}
```

Note that `T` is introduced with the trait, rather than on the method. With this setup, you conceptually don't have a single trait anymore, but rather one trait for every type (again with implicit `Sized` bounds). That means that a given type can implement the trait for different values of `T`. Like you might have both `Animal<i32>` and `Animal<u32>` implemented for`Cat`.

If you still want each type to only implement the trait once and have a single output type, you can use an associated type. The syntax for this is

```
trait Animal{
    type Weight;

    fn get_weight(&self) -> Self::Weight;
}
```

Now when you implement this trait on a type, you have to provide the output type. You could implement `Cat` by adding the line `type Weight = i32;` inside the trait implementation. Then the `get_weight` method would simply need to return `i32`, just like what you have already.